# Git branching strategies for CICD

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Just looking for thought on below branching strategies keeping CICD in mind.

1. Master branch -

   1.1 Development branch - Fork from master

   ```
             Team A branch - Fork from Development branch and merge to 
                             development branch after feature implementation 
                             for QA/Integration testing

             Team B branch - same as above

      1.1.1 Release branch - Goes in PROD
   ```

Once Team A and Team B branch merge and QA verification done, create release branch and have Final regression on it.  This release branch will go to Production.

Then merge Release to master branch.

Intent -

1. Master branch is stable and production running code is available in it.
2. Team branch can deployed on DEV environment and have required CICD configuration on server.

Any issue with this approach?

Answer (score 4):

To truly being doing CI (and CI is required to do CD) you would merge to master very regularly and not have long lived feature branches. I believe that once a day is expected for it to be "CI".

An alternative approach to the one you suggest is to have short lived developer branches for daily work. Then to have a deployment pipeline that moves each code change through a series of test stages. Only once the changes have passed each stage will they go to the next stage and be ready for production. This allows you to work on master but to remain stable and only allow passing code to enter production.

To deal with independent feature work you can use feature toggles instead of branches. You can toggle features on and push to master to test them and deploy if all is well. If not, or if there is a business need to remove a feature, you can toggle off the feature and continue to use master safely. I have seen this work very well on two products I have worked on.

I know this is very simplified but it is just to make a suggestion of alternatives for you and hopefully to help. You can learn more about implementing these techniques on a bunch of blogs and stackoverflow answers
- http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles
- http://www.paulhammond.org/2010/06/trunk/alwaysshiptrunk.pdf
- [Feature Toggles vs Feature Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434222/feature-toggles-vs-feature-branches)

Answer (score 2):

That's not true CI (by CI I mean development strategy, not tooling) because you have team branches meaning the teams' work is not integrated until merged into master - there are always teams whose work is not visible to other teams and which doesn't see work from other teams (thus open to **the rebase/merge hell**).

For true CI strategy **all** teams would work on `master` (if really pulling task branches they'd be merged back into master **very** fast, not more than a few days lifespan) - everybody is practically on the same page.

A CI tool (and maybe a CD tool in a staging environment) would keep an eye on `master` health.

Whenever `master` is `current release`-ready or when changes for the `next release` start colliding with the `current release` (release divergence) the `current_release` branch is pulled and will **never** be merged back into master (such merges would be a big problem due to release divergence). Any bug fixes in `current_release` (if applicable to `master` as well) would be cherry-picked and double-committed (just because a fix is OK on one branch it doesn't mean it's OK on another branch).

The `current_release` branch is practically your production branch. It needs it's own CI/CD setup, tailored on the `current release` features. Production builds are just labels on this branch.

The `master` branch continues to evolve towards `next release`.

Rinse and repeat.

You can also have further sub-branches of `current_release` for multi-level releases (major/minor/etc), which are also **never** merged back into their parent branch. The relationship between each such sub-branch and its parent is exactly as the relationship between `current_release` and `master`.

Comment: my CI/CD pipeline is setup this way: as soon as feature branch is merged into master the pipeline kicks off does the build, tests, deploys to uat. At this point i have a manual verification step, only after that the feature goes out to production. If feature1 is awaiting approval and feature2 arrives, once frature2 gets approved it will get deployed. But because feature2 arrived after feature1 the code already has feature1. Therefore even if feature1 was not approved, it gets deployed. How would you solve this?

Comment: @M.AliIftikhar Feature branches, approvals, etc => long lived branches - that's not really CI. See this answer for how this could be done IMHO: https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/6077/47 You'd only enable the flags/toggles when the feature is approved.